# parsing csv data in javascript not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, csv

I am parsing the csv file in javascript using the below logic. The logic works correctly in firefox browser but on chrome browser, the output is different.

```
 var r = new FileReader();
 r.onload = function (e) {
   contents = e.target.result;
     $scope.$apply(function () {
       $scope.fileReader = contents;
        contents = contents.replace(/\r\n+/g, ",");
        reqObj.names = contents.split(",");
        defer.resolve("Succesfully executed");
     });
  };
r.readAsText(file);
```

Output in Firefox :
    names: ["pradeep", "naveen", "kiran"]
Output in Chrome :
    names: ["pradeep\nnaveen\nkiran"]

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: check maybe you're not running scripts in chrome

Comment: Additionally you can call a get method inside a ready function

Comment: @claudios can you please let me know what does `/\r\n+/g` mean in javascript

Comment: `.replace(/\r\n+/g, ",")` replaces a CR followed with 1+ LF symbols with a comma multiple times. I guess it should have been written as `.replace(/(?:\r?\n)+/g, ",")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.replace(/\r\n+/g, ",")` part of code replaces multiple occurrences of a CR followed with one or more LF symbols with a comma. E.g., it will replace with a comma `"\r\n\n\n\n\n\n"` or `"\r\n"`, but will never find `"\n\n\n\n"`.

Since linebreaks can be defined as CRLF, CR, LF, you may change that part to

```
.replace(/(?:\r?\n|\r)+/g, ",")
```

to replace CRLF/LF/CR type of linebreaks.

```js
var s = "pradeep\r\nnaveen\nkiran\rhere";
console.log(s.replace(/(?:\r?\n|\r)+/g, ","));
```